# Changing the state of a component that isn't directly handling the event in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To better understand my question, take a look at my component diagram: https://app.box.com/s/rkq9bhyzs00971x6xgpq8exmvu4zzjlt

By looking at the image, you can see I essentially have a component structure of

```
Browse Widget 
  -Main Menu
  -Display
    -SubMenu
      -SubCategory
      -SearchBar
    -Video Display
```

My Display Component houses all the components that pull from an API. But they are dependent on knowing the tab that the MainMenu component has as active to make the right query. Every time a Tab is clicked, I want to update the state of Display (with a new call from the API). Is this possible?

I am a bit lost on how to change state on a component that isn't directly the one handling the event itself?

Would I need to change my component structure, or perhaps is there a better way to do this? Any Examples you can point to/make?

Comment: I think you can create a JavaScript custom event to trigger on tab change and add a listener in the display component that react on that event

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Not exactly the example I was looking for, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend keeping track of the active tab and managing all the API calls from the DisplayController component.  Using the structure below should be enough to get you started.  The data-fetching functions live within the Display component, and are passed down to other components via callbacks in props.

```
var DisplayController = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            active_tab: 0, display_data: [], 
            tabs: [{name: 'Tab 0', tab_id: 0}, {name: 'Tab 1', tab_id: 1}, {name: 'Tab 2', tab_id: 2}]
        };
    }
    changeTab: function(tab_id){
        this.setState({active_tab: tab_id}, apiCall);
    }
    apiCall: function(){
        //make api call based off of this.state.active_tab
        //this.setState({display_data: whatever you get back from api})
    }
    render: function(){
        dprops = {
            tabs: this.state.tabs.
            changeTab: this.changeTab,
            active_tab: this.state.active_tab,
            display_data: this.state.display_data
        };
        return (<MainMenu {...dprops}/>);
    }
});

var MainMenu = React.createClass({
    changeTab: function(tab_id){
        this.props.changeTab(tab_id);
    },
    render: function(){
        tabs = this.props.tabs.map(function(tab){
            return <Tab onClick={this.changeTab.bind(tab.tab_id)} name={tab.name} key={tab.tab_id}/> 
        }.bind(this));
        return(
            <div>
                {tabs}
                <Display {...this.props} />
            </div>
        );

    }
});

var Tab = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        // make your tab component here from this.props.name
    }
});
var Display = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        // make your display component here using data from this.props 
    }
});
```

Comment: I noticed that you used SubMenu, did you mean to use MainMenu (like in my components?). Also wouldn't this assume a parent/child relationship. I am looking for Display to know what is going on in Main Menu (its sibling).

Comment: I tried to clarify the naming in my edit.  It is good to have a parent component (DisplayController) managing the data in its state, then its child components can react to changes in state via props.  This maintains consistency across your components while only having to update the data in one place.

Comment: thank you. Sorry to bother with another question,  but where would you listen for the changeTab event? Are you placing onClicks on the tabs themselves? And if so how does that make changeTab in DisplayController run?

Comment: Yes, the onClick listener is attached to each tab.  When a Tab is clicked, the MainMenu changeTab function is called with the corresponding tab_id passed into the function.  This in turn calls the callback from props (which is originally from DisplayController), passing the tab_id argument.  This function then sets the state of active_tab using the proper tab_id.  Let me know if that answers your question.